# using integer variables in switch statements in java

Tags: java, switch-statement, conditional-statements

I recently encountered a situation that is somewhat similar to this.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int a = sc.nextInt(), ... , g = sc.nextInt(), x = sc.nextInt(), y = sc.nextInt(), z;
z = x * y;
switch (z)    {
    case a : //print something 
    break;
    .
    .
    .
    case g : //print something 
    break;
    default : //print something 
    break;
}
```

I encountered an error for all the case labels. I checked through some tutorials and have not got all the answers. I need to know if I can make it work with switch statement since it is a constraint I must use.

Comment: simple: you can't use variables there. you'll have to use fixed values or if-else statements

Comment: You should also provide the error details.

Comment: java:14: error: constant expression required

Comment: I got a series of the above errors for all the statements under case labels.

Comment: "_constant expression required_" is quite expressive, it required a constant, not a variable

Comment: Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: `case` labels use compile-time constant expressions (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28), you can' t use dynamic values .

Comment: @NishanthRao again: no. this won't compile. if you need to compare to variables, you're stuck with if-else statements

Comment: What would you expect to happen if a==g==1?

Comment: To make it working you can write if statement per each case, eg., you got enough answers it is not possible to use variables in case statement :). And above you have also the reason why you cant.

Comment: What if you make the int's final

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, you can't use variables as switch cases.

Whenever you find yourself doing the same thing with multiple variables (such as assigning `sc.nextInt()` to each of the variables `a` to `g`), you should consider using a loop instead.

For example:

```
ArrayList<Integer> inputs = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  inputs.add(sc.nextInt());
}
```

Then, instead of your `switch` statement, you can simply iterate over your list.

```
for (int i : inputs) {
  if (z == i) {
    doSomething();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply generate a mapping between your integer and a method. Since all your comment state this will print something, let assume you want a `String`, so you want to "supply" a `String` based on an integer.

First, let's define some function :

```
List<Supplier<String>> functions = new ArrayList<>();
functions.add(() -> "Function #1");
functions.add(() -> "Function #2");
functions.add(() -> "Function #3");
functions.add(() -> "Function #4");
```

Then, let's create a mapping for each functions:

```
Map<Integer, Supplier<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
for(Supplier<String> s : functions){
    System.out.print("Define a key for the next function :" );
    map.put(sc.nextInt(), s);
}
```

And that's it, you have define for each function (not that if you input twice a same key, only the last function will be set to that function, a `Collection` could be used if you want)

Let's get the function and execute it to get the value :

```
System.out.println("Execute:");
String value = map.get(sc.nextInt()).get();
```

**This is a short code that doesn't prevent any `NullPointerException` from happening, this is not the topic of this answer.**

PS : don't forget to close the `Scanner`

```
sc.close();
```